# HP 570SFP+ (718904-B21) support for 1000Base-T?

Tags: networking, hp

I'm writing low-latency HFT application, so I want to use fast netwrok card which allows me to by-pass network stack.
However 10 GB connection on Stock Exchange is too expensive that's why I want to use 1000Base-T (much cheaper)

So I want to connect [HP 570SFP+](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10670756) to 1000Base-T, but in the spec I can't find support for the 1000Base-T.
A the same time corresponding Solarflare network card http://www.solarflare.com/Content/userfiles/documents/Solarflare_Onload_SFN6122F_10GbE_Adapter_Brief.pdf supports 1000Base-T

- If HP 570SFP+ supports 1000Base-T?
- If can I use SFN6122F instead of HP-branded HP 570SFP+, will it work properly, if "pure" Solarflare card is fully compatible with HP DL360p Gen8?
- If someone succeed connecting HP 570SFP+ (718904-B21) to 1000Base-T ?

Comment: You need an [infrastructure consultant](http://serverfault.com/users/107579/javapowered?tab=questions&sort=newest) who's familiar with HP equipment and finance.

Comment: @ewwhite true )

Comment: There's nothing that says that the HP 570SFP+ is incompatible with Copper SFP+ adapters. [The card is a Solarflare SFN6122F](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bJOAl.png), which works just fine with copper SFP+ transceivers. You aren't seeing what you expect to see because this is an odd use case. Manufacturers don't list every possible hardware combination.

Comment: If you have real questions about this, contact HP or Solarflare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - If HP 570SFP+ supports 1000Base-T?
> - If can I use SFN6122F instead of HP-branded HP 570SFP+, will it work properly, if "pure" Solarflare card is fully compatible with HP DL360p
>     Gen8?
> - If someone succeed connecting HP 570SFP+ (718904-B21) to 1000Base-T ?

- Sure (with a copper ethernet adapter).
- Yes.
- Yes (with a copper ethernet adapter).

(you need this)

[image]

[Product specs](http://www.solarflare.com/Content/userfiles/documents/Solarflare_SFN6122F_10GbE_Adapter_Brief.pdf): *Supports optical & copper SFP/SFP+ modules; Direct-Attach, Fiber (10G or 1G), 1G/10G combo, 1000BASE-T SFP*

The Solarflare card is just a PCIe NIC. It'll work in most server hardware. [The 570SFP+ is an HP-branded **SFN6122F** Solarflare NIC](http://www.solarflare.com/HP-Branded-10GbE-Adapters). Both are fine. Solarflare even lists the equivalent product and model numbers for you.

[image]

Look *VERY* closely at the [SFN6122F specifications](http://www.solarflare.com/Content/userfiles/documents/Solarflare_SFN6122F_10GbE_Adapter_Brief.pdf). It supports Copper SFP+ adapters and 1000-Base-T. I usually use [Finisar transceivers](http://www.finisar.com/products/optical-modules/sfp/FCLF852xP2BTL).

Comment: HP-branded is MUCH more expensive than original Solarflare version, why should I pay for this? Which exact transiver should I buy to connect to 1 Gb Ethernet? Thanks!

Comment: do you personally succeed connecting HP 570SFP+ (718904-B21) to 1000Base-T ? if so then which exact module did you used?